# MultiValueDictKeyError when you transmit data from the form to the model

Tags: python, django, forms, post

My model:

```
class MyNote(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

My form:

```
class Note(forms.Form):
    note = forms.CharField(label="Wpisz notatke", max_length=255)
```

My view:

```
def note(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Note(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = MyNote.objects.create(text=request.POST['text'], pub_date=datetime.utcnow())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('todoapps:index', kwargs={'post': post.id}))

    else:
        form = Note()

    return render(request, 'note.html', {'form': form})
```

My url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details, name='detail'),
    url(r'^note/$', views.note, name="note"),
)
```

I want to write to model things introduced in the form and display them.

I get: MultiValueDictKeyError at /todo/note/
"'text'"

Do I correctly transmit data to the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two possible things you might be trying to do here.

If `note` is supposed to be the content of the `MyNote` instance you create, your core problem is that you have two different names for the field - `text` for the model and `note` for the form. You should make the names agree, and make the `max_length` values the same.

If `note` is supplemental, you need to make sure you have a `text` input somewhere. The most natural place would be in the form class. You're also not actually doing anything with `note`, but I can't guess what you might want to do with it.

Either way, it is unusual to instantiate a form from the `request.POST`, validate it, and then not use it further and reference into `request.POST` by key. More usually, you'd use `form.cleaned_data['text']` or something, or use a `ModelForm` and just save it if valid. I would rework the whole thing as something like:

```
class MyNote(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_add_now=True)
```

`auto_add_now` causes Django to set the field to the current time when you first insert it.

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyNote
        fields = ('text',)

def note(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('todoapps:index', kwargs={'post': post.id}))
    else:
        form = Note()
    return render(request, 'note.html', {'form': form})
```

Or use a generic [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), they encapsulate that kind of logic.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer covered much of what I was writing, so I'll just add to it an explanation of the exception itself.

`MultiDictKeyError` is being raised because `text` is not found as a key in `request.POST`. The general workaround would be to use e.g. `request.POST.get('text', '')`. The arguments are "key" and "default," as in the standard `dict.get()` method. This way there is a fallback value if the key is not found, and no exception is raised. But as pointed out already, the larger problem was that `text` was not a form field.